# Why regular expressions with backreferences are not regular expressions?

Tags: regex, regular-language, backreference

[This article](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) say:

> A backreference like \1 or \2 matches the string matched by a previous
>   parenthesized expression, and only that string: (cat|dog)\1 matches
>   catcat and dogdog but not catdog nor dogcat. **As far as the theoretical
>   term is concerned, regular expressions with backreferences are not
>   regular expressions.**

Why? For what reason the `\1` became "regular expression" no longer a "regular expression"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is it a question about the theory of computation, not programming.

Comment: IMHO there are a few million programmers that would disagree with whomever made that statement.

Comment: Bohemian: It does not really matter whether someone disagrees or not. 'Regular' in this context is a technical concept with a strict definition, and simply calling irregular things regular does not change the meaning of the term. A regular expression can describe regular grammars only.  The addition of backreferences allows you to describe certain context-free and context-sensitive grammars.